# turtle.ontimer() equivalent for Zelle Graphics (python)?

Tags: python, timer, zelle-graphics

Is there an equivalent way to perform the same function as the TURTLE ontimer using Zelle Graphics and Python?

The ontimer works with Zelle, but it needs the Turtle window to open (which defeats the purpose).  I am trying to figure out a way to use the turtle.ontimer but without having to call the turtle.Screen() or any turtle window.  OR if there is another way to do it in zelle graphics.py

Answer (score 0):

Since `GraphWin` is a subclass of tkinter `Canvas`, we can invoke the same `Canvas.after()` method that Python turtle uses to implement `ontimer()`:

```
from graphics import GraphWin, Circle, Rectangle, Point

def change(a, b):
    a.undraw()
    b.draw(window)

    window.after(1000, change, b, a)  # repeat one second later

window = GraphWin("Shape Shifting", 100, 100)

circle = Circle(Point(50, 50), 20)
circle.setFill('red')
circle.draw(window)

square = Rectangle(Point(30, 30), Point(70, 70))
square.setFill('green')

change(circle, square)

window.getMouse()  # Pause to view result
window.close()  # Close window when done
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am trying to reproduce this code for two separate images : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btee9_xyx60   
This issue I am having is that I get a "stack overflow" when including the blink() function in the While True loop.

Comment: @netrate, the `blink()` function has no business being in a `while True:` loop, and a `while True:` loop has no business being in that flawed video tutorial.  I've rewritten my example achieve the effect from the video.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and help, but at some point I will be using a While True loop to deal with key presses/key events  etc, so I will need it, although I can see you don't really like them in this particular instance.  I intend on making a character move with two different images (shifting from one to another).